# RestKit - Object Mapping functions not found

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm naïvely trying to follow the [guidelines](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md) for mapping one of my CoreData classes with RestKit 0.20

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
...
RKObjectMapping *mymap =
    [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass: NSClassFromString(@"MY_CLASS")];
[mymap mapAttributes:@"field1", @"field2", nil];
```

But

> No visible @interface for 'RKObjectMapping' declares the selector 'mapAttribute'

If I type `[mymap map`, I see only these 2 functions in the completion list

```
id mappingForDestinationKeyPath:(NSString *)
id mappingForSourceKeyPath:(NSString *)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

---

An other example, when I try to use the shared `RKObjectManager`

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:map forKeyPath:@"/"];
```

It can't find the member `mappingProvider`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem with the wiki page, `mapAttributes:` is not found in the `RKObjectMapping` docs (http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html). I think the wiki page is out of date, use this one instead: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping

You should use the addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary method instead:

```
[mymapp addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"field1" : @"field1"}];
```

Also mappingProvider is from pre-0.20 rest kit, and has been replaced with response descriptors (objects which are used to determine which mapping to use for a response)

```
 RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"key_path" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:descriptor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mapping like this:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping * mymap = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MY_CLASS class] inManagedObjectStore:self.objectStore];

    mymap.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
    mymap.primaryKeyAttribute = @"MY_CLASS_ID";
    mymap.rootKeyPath = @"ROOT_PATH_OF_SERVICE";
    [mymap mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"WEB_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE1", @"DATA_MODAL_ATTRIBUTE1",
     @"WEB_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE2", @"DATA_MODAL_ATTRIBUTE2",
     @"WEB_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE3", @"DATA_MODAL_ATTRIBUTE3",
     nil];
```

Comment: `RKManagedObjectMapping` doesn't seem to there neither.

Comment: Did you import RestKit in .h file
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

Comment: Yes it's imported from my `.h`.